# converting to matrix format on excel

Tags: sql, excel

I'm looking to visualize co-authorship networks with Gephi, and I'm trying to convert my data in excel to matrix format to do so.
currently, my data is set up as:
"First Author" and  "author list", where author list corresponds to all the authors that worked on a particular paper with that author.

Is there an automatic way to convert to matrix format?
Any help would be appreciated. Or an automatic way to turn the authors listed under "author list" into vertical list format, whereby each individual author is in it's own cell.

Thank you. 
[[image]

Comment: Try text to columns for the authors list and see if it helps